# loading operating system freezes just after the OS loading screen

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

These days I noticed my system started to crash by restarting perioadically, sometimes letting me enter the OS, sometimes not. I opened the case and I noticed that one of my case coolers was not running anymore. I bought a new cooler and before installing it I made some cleaning inside the case. I removed the CPU fan and heat sink and cleaned them, I removed my video card an cleaned it. After the cleaning process I put them all together and give it a try.

Same thing. The system started to restart just after my OS logo dissapeared. Each time. I entered my BIOS and took a look over the Health of the system and there I have noticed that my CPU was at about 80 degrees celsius and the upper limit was 90. I thought that this may be caused by the solution between the CPU and heat sink. So I bought a good thermal conductor solution and applied it and the temperature never went over 50 degrees celsius. After this I reboooted my PC and guess what... Same thing. Rebooting over and over and over just after Windows logo dissapears.

I forgot to mention I had Windows 7.

I went into W7 Safe Mode and uninstalled my video driver. I rebooted my PC and this time the OS loaded completely. I went and aquired the latest driver for my video card (nVidia GTX 560 TI) and installed it. I reboooted my PC and... Crash just after logo dissapears... I repeated the Safe Mode process and I tried installing some older drivers (2013, 2015) and got the same result.

I also tried reinstalling the motherboard drivers and put the same drivers on but I got the same result.

I went online and got Ubuntu and made a bootable USB. I thought that something may be broken in my W7 OS. So I booted from USB and the Ubuntu loading screen appears. The points from the loading screen are moving nicely and just after that, the system crashed.

I do not understand where the problem is or what happened.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the system booted, check the Event Logs for hardware related errors, and research their meanings.

But based on the info you've provided, I'd suggest that if it boots with your video driver removed, but crashes with it installed, then the first suspect would be the video adapter.

Hardware (vs. software) is further shown to be the culprit by the fact that you having that same/very similar problems in two very different operating systems.

Replace your video adapter with a known-good one, and continue testing.